# In SpringBoot, Springfox 3.0.0 ApiResponse Example is not shown when rest endpoint returns Object

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a several Rest endpoints, and some of their return type is just "Object" instead of, for example `ResponseEntity<Customer>`

I'm trying to create swagger documentation using SpringFox 3.0.0 in SpringBoot 2.7.15
my pom.xml

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I created very simple endpoint, deliberatively I set return type to Object, because in this project most of the endpoinds are returning plain object. Mostly it creates a JSON object inside the method and returns it.

```java
    @Operation(
            summary = "PING PONG",
            description = "Returns a Pong"
    )
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Ping Pong", content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", examples = { @ExampleObject(name = "example1", description = "test description", value = "{\"name\": \"pong\", \"description\":\"test\"}") } ))
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = KD_KUNDEN + "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Object makePing() {
        Pong newPong = new Pong();
        newPong.setName("Pong");
        newPong.setDescription("Pong description");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(newPong);
    }
```

And unfortunately, I can't see the example or description in response part
[image: no example value]

If I change the return type to ResponseEntity and in Pong.java if I give examples with @Schema annoation it is working well

```java
public class Pong {
    @Schema(name = "name", example = "jack")
    String name;
    @Schema(name = "description", example = "example description")
    String description;
}
```

and change the return type

```java
public ResponseEntity<Pong> makePing() {
...
return ResponseEntity.ok(newPong);
```

[image: with example value]

Problem is, I have lots of endpoints and I don't want to refactor every endpoint right now. Is there any solution that I can give custom examples in Response part ?

### edit-1:

According to this link:

[<Spring Boot / Springfox> Swagger UI not showing example value and model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169386/spring-boot-springfox-swagger-ui-not-showing-example-value-and-model)

I added below line in my application.properties

`springfox.documentation.swagger.use-model-v3=false`

and use old namespaces from **io.swagger.annotations** instead of **io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations** but still no luck, I can't see the examples.